# Suma de 3 hilos

Tags: java, hilos

espero me puedan ayudar,tengo este problema de hilos... 
Crear un programa que evalúe

> p=Σdesde i=-100 hasta 100 de(seno(i))+Σdesde i=-100 hasta 100
>   de(coseno(i))+Σdesde i=-100 hasta 100 de(tangente(i))

.
Para cada término de la ecuación emplee un hilo y al final realice la suma.

Llevo esto, esto es de la suma 1 del seno...

```
public class Suma1 extends Thread{
    public Suma1(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int i;
        double s=0;
        for(i=-100;i<=100;i++){
            s+=(s+Math.sin(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Hilo 1");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Para la suma 2 del coseno es este...

```
public class Suma2 extends Thread{
    public Suma2(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int i;
        double s=0;
        for(i=-100;i<=100;i++){
            s+=(s+Math.cos(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Hilo 2");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

y para la suma 3 de la tangente, es este...

```
public class Suma3 extends Thread{
    public Suma3(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int i;
        double s=0;
        for(i=-100;i<=100;i++){
            s+=(s+Math.tan(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Hilo 3");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Este es mi main...

```
public class HiloNum7 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread hilo1=new Suma1("Proceso numero 1");
        Thread hilo2=new Suma2("Proceso numero 2");
        Thread hilo3=new Suma3("Proceso numero 3");
        Thread hilo4=new SumaTotal("Proceso numero 4");

        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
        hilo3.start();
        hilo4.start();
    }

}
```

Lo que no puedo hacer es la suma general, espero me puedan ayudar, mi idea era crear otro hilo para sumar los 3 hilos, pero no tengo ni la más mínima idea de cómo hacerlo :(

Answer (score 3):

Ya tienes un *thread* en el *thread* principal. Y para sumar tres números no necesitas un *thread* independiente.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que el *thread* principal no acabe su ejecución antes de tener los datos de los tres *threads*, y encontrar la forma de recuperar el resultado de cada *thread*.

Para lo primero, lo más directo es invocar el método `join()` de cada *thread*. Esto bloqueará el *thread* desde donde se invoca hasta que el *thread* invocado haya terminado su ejecución.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
   hilo1.join();
   hilo2.join();
   hilo3.join();
   // Aquí sabes que los tres threads han terminado. Puedes empezar el cálculo final.
}
```

Otra opción es hacer un bucle que vaya comprobando el valor de `Thread.isAlive()` hasta que las tres devuelvan `false`. Pero mejor la de más arriba.

Para obtener el valor del cada thread, por ejemplo añadiendo un atributo a cada una y guardar el resultado allí; puntos de bonificación si accedes a traves de un método `get`

```
public class Suma1 extends Thread {

   private double resultado; // Aquí guardas el resultado.

   public double getResultado() {
     return this.resultado;
   }
   ...
```

y en tu `main` solo haces `hilo1.getResultado() + hilo2.getResultado()...`.

Aparte de esto, para este tipo de trabajos `java.util.concurrent.Future` se ajusta mejor.